# how to use one insert command with different data types

Tags: php, sql, sql-insert

I'm working on a web application for a subject my question is: I have a file to use the insert command but I have different thing I want to insert, I want to insert users in a table and schedule appointments in another, do i have to make two different files for two commands or is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: You can execute multiple SQL commands in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it in one file.That's not a big deal.I think you want to say something else but you are saying something else.By the way,as per your question,
there will be two

```
mysqli_query()
```

One for for inserting users in a table and other for scheduling appointments in the same file.